# How to run parallel sagas synchrony

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I have upload file saga to server

```
function * uploadImageSaga (action: Object): Saga {
  const {name, id} = action

  const payload = {
      image: action.base64
    }

    //....upload....

  yield put(uploadFileSucc(id, name, result.link))
}

function * uploadImagesSagas (): Saga {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(ACTIONS.UPLOAD_FILE, uploadImageSaga),
  ])
}

export default uploadImagesSagas
```

And it works fine.

Problem is, when is saga called 10 times on upload 10images (browser freeze :-) )...

I want to run second after the first end, and third after the second end.. synchrony.

It is possible and how? Is there any function in saga core for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly what the `actionChannel` effect is used for. You can read about this in the saga docs here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html

In your case:

```
function * uploadImageSaga (action: Object): Saga {
  // no change to this saga from what you have
}

function * uploadImagesSagas (): Saga {
  const chan = yield actionChannel(ACTIONS.UPLOAD_FILE);
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(chan);
    yield call(uploadImageSaga, action);
  }
}

export default uploadImagesSagas
```